# What is the output of the following program in C?

Tags: c

What is the output of this C code?
//The output gives 5 hi's. I can't understand how it is 5.  I think the output may 8 hi's. So I want an explanation for this output.

```
void main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (i > 1)
                break;
        }
        printf("Hi\n");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think this should produce 8 lines instead of 5.  Then we could perhaps see where you are misunderstanding the code and explain why that's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Your **Hi** is working on this loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    printf("Hi\n");

}
```

Your inner loop has no effect on output because there is no **output statement** there

**just a break statement**
see

```
for (j = 0;j < 4; j++)
{
    if (i > 1)
       break;
}
```

that's why You have only **5 Hi on your output** according to values of i

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1):

```
for (j = 0;j < 4; j++)
{
    if (i > 1)
       break;
}
```

This for loop does nothing essentially.

Answer (score 1):

The inner `for` loop doesn't really do anything. The only thing that really happens is it checks`if (i>1)` and it gets out of the inner loop.

So the execution goes back into the outer loop and `"hi"` is printed once for every `i` value